# Activity layout jumping behind statusbar, when updated from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

### Problem

I have an activity, where my user i as able to edit different values for an entity. I have created a BottomSheetDialogFragment, where the user is able to change some time values for said entity.

When the user changes a value (here it's a time) i want to change the value the activity is showing in the background as well. However, when i update my activity view, the entire activity jumps behind the Statusbar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UggM1.jpg) (i know there is an inconsistency between the number picked and the number shown, it's a timezone thing i haven't fixed yet).

### Code

I open the BottomSheetDialogFragment with:

```
TimePickerDialogFrag.newInstance(shift!!, type).run {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        show(supportFragmentManager, "timepicker_modal")
    }
```

The BottomSheetDialogFragment communicates to the activity through a delegate pattern, defined by an interface called OnTimeChangedListener as so:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnTimeChangedListener) {
        listener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnTimeChangedListener")
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    listener = null
}

interface OnTimeChangedListener {
    fun onTimeChanged(shift: ShiftEntity)
}
```

The onTimeChanged method is called when the user spins the TimePicker widget.

The method is implemented in the activity as:

```
override fun onTimeChanged(shift: ShiftEntity) {
    this.shift = shift
    startTimeTextView?.text = TimeFormatter.formatTime(shift.startTime, "HH:mm")
    endTimeTextView?.text = TimeFormatter.formatTime(shift.endTime, "HH:mm")
}
```

I'd guess the solution is somewhere in the Activitys layout file, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".activities.myshifts.ShiftActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/myNavDrawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primaryBg"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                //Content of custom AppBar goes here. Removed for an easier overview


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    
//Actual content of activity goes here. Removed it for an easier 
overview, will add if needed.

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Already tried

I have already tried using the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attribute - adding it to both the parent view and the AppBarLayout.

Adding it to the parent layout creates a padding inside of the AppBar, as soon as the Fragment opens, like seen in the top [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjCQ1m.png)

Adding the attribute to the AppBarLayout does not make a difference.

Comment: Try this property in activity tag of your `Manifest` : `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried it. Unfortunately didn't help. Don't know if i've been unclear in question, but i don't think the SoftInputMode is relevant. The BottomSheetDialogFrag is entirely custommade

Comment: On your video with jumping activity I don't see any changes on layout - there are all dates stays unchanged. Is there any `View` that changes content after `onTimeChanged` call?

Comment: make the activity content scrollable and below that, you can add a fragment, and whenever the focus changes to fragment you can change the height of scrollable activity. this can be an alternative way where you check the focus change or maybe the height change upon click for edit.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
@Ircover i see. Something weird must have happened. It doesn't seem consistent with what i've experienced. I'll update the gif so it actually makes sense. But yes the idea is that the `TextView` containing the time, should change when the time is changed on the `TimePicker`
@AnjaniMittal So i have to change my activity to a `Fragment` and then add a `ScrollView` to it? I might try it, but it doesn't seem like a very clean solution.

Comment: What is so special about the `Supervisor` item in that list? Watching the GIF you posted, that item aligns almost perfectly with the top of your BottomSheetDialogFragment. Is it your recycler view (assuming your are using one) padding an empty item on the bottom?

Comment: @PabloBaxter i think it's coincidental that that supervisor `View` aligns with the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. I'm not entirely sure i understand your question, but i use a `LinearLayout`. I can add it to the question if you want to see it?

Comment: I believe that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I did not realise the way i inflated the BottomSheetDialogFragment would have an effect and therefore i initially didn't include that code in the question.

However removing `window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)` from the Fragment did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this attribute:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

In `BottomSheetDialogFragment` root of xml that you inflate or in your `FrameLayout` that contain your `Fragment`.